# Repository error while trying to use redis as cache in spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I wanted to use redis as cache in my spring boot app, but encountered some problems while trying to use. As it is instructed in spring documentation I added spring-boot-starter-data-redis and jedis dependencies and let the spring boot to autoconfigure it.
Even though, I have disabled redis for repositories, it getting same error ("Spring Data JPA - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.atlassian.connect.spring.AtlassianHostRepository. ") only for AtlassianHostRepository.
This repository is coming from an external dependency.

```
spring:
  data:
    redis:
      repositories:
        enabled: false
```

Is there anyone who faced this before?
Thank you.

Comment: can you try to excluding RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class